# Redirect to HTTPS and WWW in one single redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cloudflare

For my website, I have setup CloudFlare CDN. The website is hosted on Siteground. CloudFlare requires the websites to be redirected to www.

Now I have setup redirects in the htaccess file. It redirects all non-https and non-www requests to https-www versions.

Following are the rules I have used on the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

The redirect works fine. **My only problem here is that it requires 2 redirects.** Let's say my website is example.com.

When I open example.com, it first redirects to https://example.com and then it gets redirected to https://www.example.com

So, I get the response code after two redirects. 301-301-200

**Now my question is:** Is there any way to have it done in a single redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a dynamic host name? If not (sounds like), you can simplify this: if not www or not https then redirect to https/www. If the host name is static you do not need to grab it from a condition. You can name it inside the redirection rule literally:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Hello @arkascha

Thank you for the answer. I have a few questions:

How are the rules different from what I am using, other than the static name? 
I used what you suggested in the htaccess and changed the response to 302

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.learnallaboutcloud.com [QSA,R=302,END]
```

I still get two redirects, but now, one of them is 302.
301-302-200

Is there any way to get only one redirect? 301-200

And how do we place the rules in http servers host configuration in SiteGround.

Comment: Above rule set will redirect only once. If you observe two redirections then some other aspect comes into play you did not tell us about. Either some other rules, maybe in the real host configuration or simply client side caching of earlier attempts.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work well for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I hope that helps someone